# Node-Webkit Tray on click bring window to front

Tags: node-webkit

I'm new to node-webkit and have the tray created as such

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var tray = new gui.Tray({ icon: 'images/Appicon.png' });
tray.on('click', function() { console.log("what goes in here?")});
```

When the tray icon is clicked I want the window to be pulled up if it's minimized and open index.html.
Right now I get the log statement to print.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get(); 

var tray = new gui.Tray({ 
    icon: 'images/Appicon.png' 
});
tray.on('click', function() { 
    win.maximize();
});
```