# How do I know if the OSX taskbar icon of a Node-Webkit application is clicked?

Tags: macos, node-webkit

I have a Node-Webkit application on OSX and minimized it to tray. When the tray icon is clicked, the window restores.

The problem is, when the icon on OSX taskbar instead of the tray icon is clicked, nothing happens. However, the expected response is to restore the window too.

Is there any way to know if the taskbar icon is clicked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the taskbar with the menu or a trayicon? The taskbar doese not have an icon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node-Webkit Tray on click bring window to front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132365/node-webkit-tray-on-click-bring-window-to-front)

Comment: On OSX there is a taskbar icon! It seems to be called 'dock' as well... But in node-webkit, there is an API named setShowInTaskbar, so I call it a taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution finally (OSX only):

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
gui.App.on('reopen', function () {
  win.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
var win = gui.Window.get(); 

var tray = new gui.Tray({ 
    icon: 'images/icon.png' 
});
tray.on('click', function() { 
    win.maximize();
});
```